# Running 'vagrant up' generates an error

Tags: laravel, vagrant

ERROR MESSAGE

[image]

I've been following the steps [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead)

After editing, my homestead.yaml now looks like:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: D:/homestead/dev.todoparrot.com
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: dev.todoparrot.com
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/dev.todoparrot.com/public

databases:
    - homestead
```

I generated the key with Git Gui and it put it into C:/Users/User/.ssh/ automatically. I left it as is.

I created the folders: map: directory manually (D:/homestead/dev.todoparrot.com). It's empty.

Then, I ran Power Shell inside the Homestead folder (C:/Users/User/) (the main Homestead folder with homestead.yaml and other files inside).

I typed "vagrant up" into Power Shell and got this error (link at the very top). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `keys`, you're missing a `-` before the path:

```
keys:
    - C:/Users/User/.ssh/id_rsa
```